# Black screen when video players/games cover entire X display in fullscreen on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: nvidia, xorg, games, fullscreen

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 and my GPU is an NVIDIA GTX 1070, all drivers are installed and up to date. Whenever I launch a game or video player (such as VLC or mpv) in fullscreen (covering the entire X display), the screen quickly turns black. The games render normally in the Dash to Panel window preview, and every other part of the game works. This only started once I upgraded to 21.10.

This does not happen to full screen videos/applications on Firefox.

EDIT: I fixed it by enabling "Force Composition Pipeline" in Nvidia X Server Settings!

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was enabling "Force Composition Pipeline" in Nvidia X Server Settings.

Comment: That disables G-SYNC.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed in a newer driver version:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-495
```

Package version: `495.46-0ubuntu2`

Running on Ubuntu 22.04.

G-SYNC works in games like CS:GO and "Oxygen Not Included".

The previous `nvidia-driver-470` has a monitor shutdown problem in fullscreen + no composition pipeline with Ubuntu 21.10 or later.